# Eclipse properties with java aws imports

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, amazon-web-services

I am trying to write a program in java that creates and watches instances in Amazon aws service 
but the problem is that it shows errors with:

import EC2.cloudEC2Connector; 
import monitor.monitorEC2;

and according to that the entire code is full of errors in my Mac machine only but it works well
in my partners machines in Linux and Windows ... can anybody tell me how to fix the problem please??

Thanks ....

Comment: I have already installed aws plug-in and I am using eclipse Indigo

Answer (score 0):

Those classes aren't part of the AWS SDK for Java, so that's not the problem.  It looks like you're missing another library that your partner has from your classpath.